# What is epsilon algebra and why is it important in Numerical Analysis?

Tags: numerical-methods

My professor is using the following slides:

[image]

What is epsilon algebra and why is it important in Numerical Analysis?

Comment: What textbooks are being used for your class? What is your current level of mathematics?

Comment: @CarlChristian, none.

Answer (score 4):

This is a question you should ask your professor.
If they have not made it clear, then many students in the class are probably wondering about that.

The different epsilons represent small errors.
That "epsilon algebra" is nothing but first order approximation of errors.
All terms including products of epsilons is considered small and is thrown away.
All that is left is the main term without any epsilons and terms linear in the epsilons.

When errors are small, such calculations give a decent approximation of propagation of errors.
Errors are inevitable in numerical analysis, and it is important to understand how big an error you make in a calculation if you start with a given error.
There are a number of sources of error, so it is convenient to have several epsilons.

Comment: `This is a question you should ask your professor. ` --- his English is very weak.

Comment: Can you supply me with a reference for further reading?

Comment: @yahoo.com You could ask him in another language. If the teaching language is English, the professor should (but sometimes admittedly won't) be able to answer a question asked in English. If spoken communication is hard, you can send an email and ask them to clarify the matter in the next lecture. To search for further reading, use the keyword "error analysis". There are a number of resources.

Answer (score 1):

To take one example from the basic rules, note that

\begin{align}
(1+\varepsilon_1)(1+\varepsilon_2) &= 1+\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2+\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\\
&\cong 1+\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2
\end{align}

This is a reasonable assumption when epsilon is so small that products (or powers) of epsilons can be ignored for the purposes of the task.

Answer (score 0):

The is a variation of [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) and [derivations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)) is its generalization to several variables. They are important because the algebra tracks the propagation of errors in arithmetic and other numerical operations giving a good approximation to how much error is contained in the results of the operations. It is a way of automatically keeping track of derivatives which determines how sensitive the operations are in outputs relative to inputs. You can think of it as the first order approximation to a function of several variables.

The specific variation used is close to [significance arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significance_arithmetic)
 in that we replace every variable $\, x_i \,$ with 
 $\, x_i(1+\epsilon_i) \,$ where each $\, \epsilon_i^2 = 0, \,$
also $\, \epsilon_i \epsilon_j = 0, \,$
and assuming that each $\, x_i \ne 0. \,$ It is easy to verify the operation
 $\, x_i(1+\epsilon_i)\, x_j(1+\epsilon_j) = x_ix_j(1 + \epsilon_i + \epsilon_j) \,$  Notice how this is different from using
 $\, x_i + \epsilon_i \,$ where we allow $\, x_i = 0 \,$ and where 
 $\, (x_i + \epsilon_i)(x_j + \epsilon_j) = x_i x_j + (x_i \epsilon_j + x_j \epsilon_i). \,$ Also notice that if $\, x_i = x_j = x, \,$ then
 $\, x_i(1 + \epsilon_i) - x_j(1 + \epsilon_j)  = 0 + x(\epsilon_i - \epsilon_j)\,$ but the difference has **lost all** significance.

The epsilon algebra is a simple method compared to the more advanced [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) which can be used to put bounds on rounding and measurement errors in computation. The advantage of epsilon algebra is that simple rules of calculation are sufficient compared to the complicated calculation rules of interval arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

The first thought which comes to mind are  those of **error** or **estimation** of approximation. How far is an iterative process of the supposed **limit** object.

If you have a small quantity, say $\varepsilon=10^{-4}$, then $\varepsilon^2=10^{-8}$ is even smaller. Worst for $\varepsilon^n$ if $n\ge 3$.